# How do I create a new column of incremented values from a column containing a range of values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm quite new to Pandas/Python so apologies if this is quite straight forward. I'm working on a project at work and could do with some help.

I have some data describing the positions of blood samples in a storage box.
I currently have the range of positions occupied by a certain number of samples in the column named 'Position' in the form '1_5' meaning these samples occupy the positions 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 in the storage box.

[dataframe pictured here][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMhZm.jpg .

What I want is for each sample in the the range provided to have its own individual position number. **So rather than the data currently looking like this:**

Patient -    Box    - Position

patient 1 - box 1 - 97_100

patient 1 - box 1 - 97_100

patient 1 - box 1 - 97_100

patient 1 - box 1 - 97_100

patient 1 - box 2 - 30_32

patient 1 - box 2 - 30_32

patient 1 - box 2 - 30_32

**I want it to look like this:**

Patient -    Box    -    Position

patient 1 - box 1 - 97

patient 1 - box 1 - 98

patient 1 - box 1 - 99

patient 1 - box 1 - 100

patient 1 - box 2 - 30

patient 1 - box 2 - 31

patient 1 - box 2 - 32

Anybody know a way to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Position'] = (df.groupby('Position').cumcount() + 
                 df['Position'].str.split('_').str[0].astype(int))
print (df)
     Patient    Box  Position
0  patient 1  box 1        97
1  patient 1  box 1        98
2  patient 1  box 1        99
3  patient 1  box 1       100
4  patient 1  box 2        30
5  patient 1  box 2        31
6  patient 1  box 2        32
```

**Detail**:

Get counts per groups by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
print (df.groupby('Position').cumcount())
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    0
5    1
6    2
dtype: int64
```

and add extracted first value of column `Position` before `_` converted to `integer`:

```
print (df['Position'].str.split('_').str[0].astype(int))
0    97
1    97
2    97
3    97
4    30
5    30
6    30
Name: Position, dtype: int32
```